# Image Upload in Laravel unable to be viewed on shared hosting

Tags: php, laravel

I created a symbolic link on local system with
`php artisan storage:link`
this allows laravel to link files from the

> public/storage

folder to the

> storage/app/public
> folder.

I am able to view the images stored in the storage folder with `{{asset(#Path)}}`
when I work locally on my system.

However, when I upload it to the webserver, the image cannot be found. Although the image was uploaded successfully to the

> storage/app/public/images

folder and the

> public/storage/images

folder is empty. I cannot point out exactly where the problem lies.
I have tried to modify the `config/filesystems.php` file but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Did you also create the symbolic on your server?
Also, you might want to really check that symbolic link if you are switching from OS, eg: local -> Windows, and server -> Linux.

One easy thing to do to know if there is no other problem (like CORS) would be to actually put the image where it should be and see if it works.
If it shows up, then just fix your symbolic link, if it doesn't then you have an other problem, that you can see using the devtools.

*this should be a comment but I still can't post comments.*

Comment: Hi, look at this documentation from the laravel docs: 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/filesystem#the-public-disk

Comment: Yes, I know about storage:link, my question is, did you execute `php artisan storage:link` on your server? Don't expect the symbolic link you created on your locl machine to work on your server.